How to debug main.dart.js in flutter web app
I have a flutter web app that I am trying to deploy but when I run it locally on my machine of if I try to run it on the server I get this in the browser console:

I don't know how to debug and fix this issue especially since the main.dart.js file is created when I run flutter build web.
I think I am getting a blank screen displayed because of this error.
Does anyone know how to debug and fix this problem? Please let me know if you need any more information to help me with this.
Thanks
